# Removing Desktop directory from opt folder

Tags: permissions

I've just recently started using Ubuntu 16.4 LTS, converting from iOS.  I had just downloaded a file and moved it from the downloads folder to the desktop.  I was using the terminal to try to copy it to my /opt folder, but somehow, I copied my entire Desktop to the /opt folder.  Now, I can't seem to get rid of the directory since I have insufficient permission.  Can anyone help me with this problem?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you managed to copy a folder into a system directory, you should have enough rights to remove it from there.

You can use `sudo` which gives you `root` permissions.

e.g. the following command will remove the `/opt/Desktop` folder

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/Desktop
```

> `sudo - execute as super user`
>
> `rm -rf - recursively remove all files of this folder and its sub-folders`
>
> Note: please be careful when running `sudo rm -rf /folder` as it will
>   remove the content of this folder and all of its sub-folders

Comment: It worked; thank you for your help.  Hopefully I'll get more familiar with the Ubuntu ecosystem soon.